How to access AG-Grid Grid API from outside vue component?
My app has a Home vue component and an AgGrid vue component. AgGrid is rendered inside Home and contains the actual AG-Grid and Home looks like this:
<template>
  <AgGrid :rows="rows" :columns="columns" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onBeforeMount } from 'vue'
import AgGrid from '@/components/AgGrid.vue'
import { rows, columns } from '@/services/connector'

const rows = ref()
const columns = ref()

onBeforeMount(async () => {
  rows.value = rows()
  columns.value = columns()
})
</script>

AgGrid looks like this:
<template>
    <AgGridVue
    :rowData="rows"
    :columnDefs="columns"
  />
</template>

<script setup>
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css'
import { AgGridVue } from 'ag-grid-vue3'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  rows: {
    type: Array,
    required: true
  },
  columns: {
    type: Array,
    required: true
  }
})
</script>

How do I access the AG-Grid Grid API of AgGrid from Home?

You should be able to do that thanks to template refs.
<AgGrid :rows="rows" :columns="columns" ref="gridRef" />

then
gridRef.value.specificGridApiMethod()

PS: not sure but maybe you gonna need to expose this API to outside components too.

As the documentation indicates:

The gridReady event fires upon grid initialization but the grid may
not be fully rendered.

In other words, it is an event that fires right after the Ag-grid becomes available on the screen (there is not necessarily mounted data, for that, on this same page, there is something that fits).
Under Common Uses, there is something to help you:

Event listener setup.

And how do you do that?
Simply add @grid-ready to the Ag-Grid component by calling the function you want, in this example, we'll use “onGridReady”:
 <AgGridVue
    :rowData=“rows”
    :columnDefs=“columns”
    @grid-ready=“onGridReady”
  />

Then, in the called function you can trigger an event for the parent component, passing the ag-grid API:
const gridApi = ref({});
const onGridReady = ({ api }) => {
  console.log('--jsdno0 debug grid is ready');
  gridApi.value = api;
};

Use defineEmits to declare the event to be fired and call it inside your onGridReady.
const gridApi = ref({});
const emit = defineEmits(['grid-ready']);

const onGridReady = ({ api }) => {
  console.log('--jsdno0 debug grid is ready');
  gridApi.value = api;
  emit('grid-ready', api); // Emits the event for the parent component
};

Inside your Home component, receive the event emitted by the child component and create a function to perform some action with the received API, in the example I used handleGridReady.
<template>
  <AgGrid :rows=“rows” :columns=“columns” @grid-ready=“handleGridReady” />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onBeforeMount } from 'vue'
import AgGrid from '@/components/AgGrid.vue'
import { rows, columns } from '@/services/connector'

const rows = ref()
const columns = ref()

onBeforeMount(async () => {
  rows.value = rows()
  columns.value = columns()
})

const handleGridReady = (api) => {
  console.log('API received from child: ', api);
};
</script>

